# Evaluate the integral $\int_{r\leq R}\frac{\mathrm dr}{r^2-k^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to evaluate:
$$\int_{0\leq r\leq R}\frac{\mathrm dr}{r^2-k^2}$$
Where $k$ is a complex number with positive imaginary part and non zero real part. $R$ is a positive number.

By Cauchy's theorem I could say that the integral on a contour away from $k^2$ is $0$, but this doesn't really help in  the explicit computation.
I could also try to find a primitive directly, but that would be the $\arctan$ complex function which I'm not sure how to handle.

Any help welcome.

Comment: $arctan$ isn't what you need. Try partial fractions.

Comment: Is the domain of the integral $0 \le r \le R$ or $-\infty < r \le R$?

Comment: $0\leq r\leq R$ is the right domain

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2k} \left[ \frac{1}{r-k} - \frac{1}{r+k} \right] = \frac{1}{r^2 - k^2}.$

Comment: When $R$ goes to $\infty$, the integral equals some constant times $\log(-1)$. This is confusing: $\log(-1)$ could be $i\pi$ as well as $-3i\pi$, does it mean that the integral is not well defined?